# Amplify AppSync results cached

Tags: next.js, graphql, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

I setup a website using AWS Amplify Hosting. The front-end is NextJS. I am using the API Category in the Amplify Backend, which is in turn is using AWS App Sync and DynamoDB. **Caching is set to None, in the AppSync API.**

I am using NextJS, because I need to support some server-side rendering (different feature/topic). It happens that I am calling the API.query operation from within the `getServerSideProps()`, and somewhere, somehow, data is being cached and I cannot clear the cache.

Using the amplify studio (website), I navigate to the Content section, and delete records. Even after several days, the records I deleted are still returned by my API.query calls. **I have redeployed the build and updated the cache-control header**, and I am still facing the same issue.

I can't figure out where the caching is happening. If it is at CloudFront, how do I manage this? I don't have access to the CloudFront distribution; Amplify hides that.

Here is the call I am making:

```
    const clientReviewsQueryResults = await (
        API.graphql({
            query: listClientReviewModels,
            authMode: 'API_KEY',
            variables: { limit: 10, filter: reviewFilter}
        })
    );
```

Here is my NextJS Config file:

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  swcMinify: true,
}
const withBundleAnalyzer = require("@next/bundle-analyzer")({
  enabled: process.env.ANALYZE === "true",
});

module.exports = withBundleAnalyzer({
  ...nextConfig,
  async redirects() {
    return [
      {
        source: '/blog',
        destination: '/',
        permanent: true,
      },
      {
        source: '/contact',
        destination: '/',
        permanent: true,
      },
    ]
  },
})
```

Here are the HTTP Response Headers I get:

**Response**

```
:status: 200
Cache-Control: private, no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Date: Tue, 13 Jun 2023 14:25:53 GMT
Server: CloudFront
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Via: 1.1 9adef5b1c5fc9ca80d6f4f8d19e103a2.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
x-amz-cf-id: N35s80oU9t24Tq-gfsywrlMfahxARl_kJKBK58PBjoU4c8Fytu6Bkw==
x-amz-cf-pop: SEA19-C3
x-cache: Miss from cloudfront
x-powered-by: Next.js
```

In summary - I would like to be able to NOT cache calls made to the backend (API/AppSync/etc) when using `API.query({...})`

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what was going on. When I delete a record in the Amplify console, in the Content section, it doesn’t actually delete the data in the underlying DynamoDB table. Rather, it sets a “_deleted” field to true, and sets a ttl on the record to 30 days. The Amplify console ignores the record, however, the API.query function does not ignore it. Further, the _deleted field is not defined in the GraphQL schema, and thus the field cannot be used in a filter expression.